# Substring to remove everything before first period and after second

Tags: java, substring

So I have a filename that looks like this:

myFile.12345.txt

If I wanted to end up with just the "12345" how would I go about removing that from the filename if the 12345 could be anywhere between 1 and 5 numbers in length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure that there would be 2 periods `.` for sure

```
String fileName = string.split("\\.")[1]
```

Comment: Hrm, it's complaining about being called from a static context.

Comment: you seems to be accessing non static member variable from static method

Comment: @Damien.Bell My guess: you tried `String.split`. `string` is just a variable in Jigar's example.

Comment: Yep, felt like a total idiot after I realized this too... it has been a long day (11+ hours) of coding, so I'm fried, thanks for pointing that out @MarkoTopolnik and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this

```
String s="ghgj.7657676.jklj";
String p = s.substring(s.indexOf(".")+1,s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to extract all the numbers, you could use a simple regex to remove all the non-digits characters:

```
String s = "myFile.12345.txt";
String numbers = s.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
System.out.println(numbers); //12345
```

Note: It would not work with `file12.12345.txt` for example

Answer (score 2):

```
static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)$");
...
...
...
Matcher m = P.matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
  //String first = m.group(1);
  String middle = m.group(2);
  //String last = m.group(3);
  ...
}
```